# Spring Data Jpa some List data query find id doing 70000time then occur com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa, connection-pooling

I ask some Huge List data select id 700000 time;

like this.

example

```
   List<SomeEntity> rntList = someArraydatasizeis700000 //maybe that size is700000

    List<SomeEntity> collect = rntList.stream().map(key -> {
        Optional<OtherEntity> rnt = mailrepo.findById(key.getId());
        if (rnt.isPresent()) {
            //some update 
            rnt.setSomedata(key.getData())

            return rnt.get();
            } else {
             return key;
             }
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());

somerepo.saveAll(collect)
```

And my Spring data jpa setting

```
jdbcurl=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/jsbp?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=UTC&&useSSL=false&rewriteBatchedStatements=true
jdbcdrive=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
 properties.setProperty("initialSize", "100");
 properties.setProperty("maxActive", "100");  
 properties.setProperty("maxWait", "10000");  
 properties.setProperty("maxIdle", "100");    
 properties.setProperty("minIdle", "20");
```

properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect");

And when spring insert data then occur error like this.

```
 WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
 ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions - Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.


org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:275)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:138)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy156.findByMailkey(Unknown Source)
    at com.jsbp.www.admin.schedulesConf.runscheduler.BlcokThreadMake.lambda$makeThread$6(BlcokThreadMake.java:136)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:566)
    at com.jsbp.www.admin.schedulesConf.runscheduler.BlcokThreadMake.makeThread(BlcokThreadMake.java:144)
    at com.jsbp.www.admin.schedulesConf.web.SchedulerContTest.test(SchedulerContTest.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:532)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:114)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1984)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1914)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1892)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:937)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2689)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2672)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2506)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2501)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:395)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1507)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1537)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1553)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor115.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:402)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy204.getSingleResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:214)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:905)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:830)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:154)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:145)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:205)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:106)
    ... 99 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: The driver was unable to create a connection due to an inability to establish the client portion of a socket.

This is usually caused by a limit on the number of sockets imposed by the operating system. This limit is usually configurable. 

For Unix-based platforms, see the manual page for the 'ulimit' command. Kernel or system reconfiguration may also be required.

For Windows-based platforms, see Microsoft Knowledge Base Article 196271 (Q196271).
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:152)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:849)
    ... 112 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65)
    ... 114 more
```

What i do change for insert?

this case i some list data check exist or not.
Maybe some data exist i'll update but not exist i'll insert

that is my logic

Do i use @QueryInsert()?
or native query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What did you use datasource Class?

I hear that DataSource are has version.

develop and production

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-sql